# Why my Ajax load the php page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a HTML form (with id = "registro"), it's send by POST to a PHP page.
I wanna validate it by Ajax but it's still load the PHP page.

Excuseme I'm just learning code and english and if you know a better way to do this I really appreciate it.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(init);

function init(){
    var usuario = $('#usuario').val;
    var contrasena = $('#contrasena').val;

    $("#aceptar").click(validacion);
}
function validacion(){
    var valido = true;

    if(usuario == ""){
        $("p").text("Ingrese un nombre de usuario.");
        valido = false;
    }
    if(contrasena == ""){
        $("p").text("Ingrese una contraseña.");
        valido = false;
    }

    if(valido){
        envioAjax();
    }else{
        return false; //I think here is the problem but I don't know.
    }
}
function envioAjax(){
    $.post("registro.php", $('#registro').serialize(), recibir);
    return false;
}
function recibir(respuesta){
    $("p").text(respuesta);
}
```

Comment: You need to prevent the default click/submit  action.

Comment: @JayBlanchard  `return false` should do that, assuming no errors are thrown beforehand

Comment: True @charlietfl, we'd need to see the actual click handling code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax problem using `val()` and you probably can't get the 2 input values until user has inserted them

```
 var usuario = $('#usuario').val //undefined
```

Should be

```
 var usuario = $('#usuario').val();
```

However you should get those values within the `validacion()` method

```
function validacion(){
    /* now get the values */
    var usuario = $('#usuario').val();
    var contrasena = $('#contrasena').val();
    /* remainder of your validation code/ ajax */

}
```

What you currently would have is `usuario` would be `undefined` and therefore will not be equal to empty string. Thus `if(usuario  =='')` is never true as it is the same as `if(undefined == '')`